# Reverse transfer of values from bash to LO macro

Tags: bash, global-variables, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I’m a beginner and I’m using in a LibreOffice macro the shell command:

```
    Shell(Pathname, Windowstyle, Param, bSync)
```

to activate some bash scripts. Reading the blogs I understand that variables value transfer is one-way, top to down. Is there a way to have back to the calling macro some values, integers or strings, or it is necessary to go throughout a .tmp file? If possible I would like to have some example code.

Thanks to KamilCuk I posted on LibreOffice and I received the answer: there is no way. The only one is using a file!

Comment: I suggest to ask on https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/ if not here, there are more libreoffice gurus there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on LibreOffice, as suggested: only way is to use a file.